# How add background image to UIControl

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2, uicontrol

I create 3rd party keyboard and i try add background to my keys. I use `UIControl` for my keys, without storyboard.

I have several types of buttons and try to add background `UIView` for my characters.

```
let img = UIImage(named:"KeyBackground")
            var bgImage: UIImageView?
            bgImage = UIImageView(image: img)
            bgImage!.frame = keyboardKey.frame
            keyboardKey.addSubview(bgImage!)
            keyboardKey.sendSubviewToBack(bgImage!)

            keyboardKey.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

But is don't work.

I try to add background image like this:

```
keyboardKey.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"KeyBackground")!)
```

But is looks bad...
[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it's so easy. My keyboardKey.frame, at the time of the call this method, have frame = 0, 0, 0, 0.

Night a bad time for work:)

Answer (score 1):

The background looks like that because the size of your image is a little smaller than the size of each key, and the image is being tiled (repeated to fill the space - so each key contains the background image and pieces of the surrounding tiles to the right, bottom, and bottom-right).

The [UIColor(patternImage:) docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIColor/initWithPatternImage:) say that

> During drawing, the image in the pattern color is tiled as necessary to cover the given area.

Your first solution probably didn't work because you inserted your UIImageView as the bottom-most subview - I assume another (opaque) view was on top of it. What type of UIControl are you using? UIButton, for example, already provides some "background image" support out of the box.